# MongoDB full text search over email address matching all values and possible fix taking too much time comparitively

Tags: mongodb

When trying to search for part of an email address, I see an issue -

When I search for a part of the email address containing the domain (eg- "prateeknar@gma" when email ID is "prateeknar@gmail.com"), I get all the records in the Collection.

`db.getCollection('Employee').find({$text:{$search:"prateeknar@gm"}}) -. returns all records in the collection`

However, when I search for just the username or username followed by "2" (eg - "prateeknar" or "prateeknar@"), I get the right results.

`db.getCollection('Employee').find({$text:{$search:"prateeknar"}}) -. returns the results properly`

As pointed out by @AlexBlex - delimiting with double quotes is a solution.This solves the issue but it adds a lot of latency. Can we reduce the latency in some other way?

What is the issue? How can I fix this ?

Comment: Don't confuse text search and regexps. Text search considers `@` a word separator and returns all records that have at least one of words `prateeknar` or `gm`. The later apparently matches "all records in the collection"

Comment: @AlexBlex adding quotes to delimit it seems to add in a lot of latency. Any fix for this ?

Comment: Check if https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#index-use is faster.

Answer (score 1):

Use *regex* For searching

Ref Link : [mongoRegex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/)

```
db.Employee.find({email:{$regex:"text"}})
```

Answer (score 0):

try to remove the text index and do normal index on your email filed.

then you can do a simple regex to find it

```
db.getCollection('Employee').find({email:/^prateeknar@gm/})
```

Answer (score 0):

Mongo DB search by index returns true if some of the string matches something in the collection

when you search for **"prateeknar"**, only one document matches that

however when you search for **"prateeknar@gm"** probably most of your documents match @gm and mongo is returning those also, try adding some emails that aren't gmail and you should get no return from those